# Create Unique field in Codeigniter DBForge Migration

Tags: codeigniter, migration, codeigniter-2, dbforge

How can I make the `financial_year` field as unique using `Codeigniter Dbforge` migration?

```
function up() {

    $this->dbforge->add_field(array(
        'id'    =>  array(
            'type'              =>  'INT',
            'constraint'        =>  11,
            'unsigned'          =>  TRUE,
            'auto_increment'    =>  TRUE
        ),
        'financial_year'    =>  array(
            'type'              =>  'VARCHAR',
            'constraint'        =>  20
        ),
        'start_date'    =>  array(
            'type'              =>  'DATE'
        ),
        'end_date'  =>  array(
            'type'              =>  'DATE'
        ),
        'status'    =>  array(
            'type'              =>  "ENUM",
            'constraint'        =>  "'Active','Inactive'",
            'default'           =>  "Active"
        ),
        'created_on'    =>  array(
            'type'              =>  'TIMESTAMP'
        )
    ));

    $this->dbforge->add_key('id', TRUE); // add `id` as primary key

    $this->dbforge->create_table('financial_year'); // create table schema
}
```

Answer (score 12):

There is not an option to do that in the database driver.

either write the SQL to create the table manually, or (and this isn't what i would recommend) change the DB_forge.php and your database driver. (eg mysql_forge.php) to have unique keys. looking at the code i guess you would just have a class variable called 'unique_keys' and follow the code where 'keys', and 'primary keys' are to add unique keys in.

another option is to use the dbforge as written, then just modifiy the table after creation

```
$this->db->query('ALTER TABLE `financial_year` ADD UNIQUE INDEX (`financial_year`)');
```

Comment: Should not it be ```$this->db->query``` ? This breaks my migration

Comment: Correct - it should be: `$this->db->query('ALTER TABLE financial_year ADD UNIQUE INDEX (financial_year)');`

Comment: The down migration in this case would be:
`$this->db->query('ALTER TABLE financial_year DROP INDEX (financial_year)');`

Answer (score 9):

This question is marked as CodeIgniter2 - @pgee70 Answer is correct

but

CodeIgniter3 supports the creation of unique fields.
Just add

```
'unique'            => TRUE
```

to the field

In this case:

```
'financial_year'    =>  array(
        'type'              =>  'VARCHAR',
        'constraint'        =>  20,
        'unique'            => TRUE
    ),
```

see 
[CodeIgniter user_guide](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/forge.html?highlight=db_forge#adding-fields)